# How load firmwares from non-free cd-including-firmware Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, firmware

I downloaded [unofficial non-free Debian DVD including-firmware](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.9.0+nonfree/) and put it on flash memory using rufus in dd mode. But while trying to install Debian, it says I should insert media containing firmware. Isn't it inside the installing flash memory?

Comment: You mean the message after selecting the keyboard when the installer tries to detect and mount the cd, right?

Comment: Yes. Finally, I installed it manually after installing Debian!

Comment: I guess I meant something different, but it's nice to see you could fix it!